# Was the Jedha temple site inspired by the Acropolis hill?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, real-location

The [Acropolis of Athens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acropolis_of_Athens) was the religious center in ancient Greece. In *Rogue One*, the [Temple of the Kyber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Kyber) was the religious center on Jehda. In my opinion, the structural concept of these two look very much alike.

[image]

Could it be confirmed that the site on Jedha was inspired by the ancient structures from our history?

Comment: While a good answer would have a source from a production team member on the influence here specifically, it also resembles the hilltop fortress of [Masada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Masada), which the Romans sieged for a year while building an earthen ramp. The Empire did not need to build a ramp to lay siege to Jedha City.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google, most speculators (and one unsourced trivia bit from a newspiece) compare Jedha City directly to [Masada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Masada), a hilltop fortress which was under siege by the Roman Empire in 74 B.C. The Roman legion surrounded the hill and built an earthen ramp over the course of a year. The holdouts in the fortress committed mass suicide before the ramp was complete.

Visually, the hilltop heavily resembles Jedha City, in both concept art and shots in the film itself. Masada is a very famous exmaple of Roman legion siege tactics and it provides a lot of good visual & story parallels to the dynamic between the rebels and the Empire in Rogue One.